# View To Show Tagged Comments Via Arguments

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

Hello i like how you can add taxonomy to comments now in D7. Im having a few problems though creating a View that will take a tid contextual filter and show the comments in the taxonomy page as a block. Has anyone managed to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: sorry i should mention that i am fine for showing a block showing comments that are attached to nodes that have the term. This is with Comment: Content relationship and a (Content) Content: Has taxonomy term ID context filter. ah wait a sec......brb

Comment: bah i thought i had it there. i added the realtionship (req) Field: newtag where newtag is the term ref field i added to my comments but this relationship is not available to me when adding the taxonomy term ID context filter. Im still stuck :(

Comment: nope its all working fine. Contextual filters
(term from field_newtag) Taxonomy term: Term ID, Relationships
Field: newtag - fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Relationships Field: newtag (whatever your term referance field is called)

Contextual filters (term from field_newtag) (add relationship from above)